# Директивы препроцессора

Tags: c++

Заинтересовал вопрос: может ли иметь место такое понятие, как препроцессорная псевдорекурсия в языке С++? Или в языке как-то установлены способы реагирования на подобные ситуации? К примеру, следующий код компилируется и выполняется.

```
#include <iostream>

#define true false
#define false true

int main()
{
    if (true)
        std::cout << 'a';
    else
        std::cout << 'b';
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Похоже препроцессор определяет подобное зацикливание и "тихо" прекращает подстановки, вызывающие его.

Посмотрите следующие примеры:

file a.c

```
#define true false
#define false true

#define a b
#define b c
#define c d
#define d a

int
main ()
{
  if (true)
    cout << true;
  else
    cout << false;

  int b = 110;
  cout << a << '\n';
  cout << b << '\n';
  cout << c << '\n';
  cout << d << '\n';

}

c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ g++ -E a.c
# 1 "a.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command line>"
# 1 "a.c"
# 13 "a.c"
int
main ()
{
  if (true)
    cout << true;
  else
    cout << false;

  int b = 110;
  cout << a << '\n';
  cout << b << '\n';
  cout << c << '\n';
  cout << d << '\n';

}
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $
```

Теперь чуть изменим #defin-ы (привожу только их)

```
#define true false
#define false true

#define a b
#define b c
//#define c d
#define d a
```

Закомментарили define c d, т.е. разорвали цикл (или рекурсию) "переподстановок"

```
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ g++ -E a.c
# 1 "a.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command line>"
# 1 "a.c"
# 13 "a.c"
int
main ()
{
  if (true)
    cout << true;
  else
    cout << false;

  int c = 110;
  cout << c << '\n';
  cout << c << '\n';
  cout << c << '\n';
  cout << c << '\n';

}
```

Смотрите сами. Вот, собственно, и все.

Comment: На всякий случай - вот [**референс**][1], который подтверждает поведение, проверенное вами.

[1]: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Self_002dReferential-Macros.html

Answer (score 3):

Это вряд ли можно назвать псевдорекурсией. Это скорее "перепереопределение" что ли =)

Вот вы сами проверяли, как работает данный код? Сначала вы делаете (true===false), а затем 
(false===true). Компилятору легко обнаружить эту неопределенность и в итоге все становится, как было до первого `#define`. Как известно, `(int)true == 1, а (int)false == 0`. Вот и все - все становится на свои места =)

**UPD:**

Смысл от такой связки дефайнов будет лишь в том случае, если до вызова первого в коде встретится хоть одно значение `false`.Например:

```
// смысла не имеет
...
#define true false
#define false true
...
int main()
{
bool a=true;
bool b=true;
}

// смысл имеет, но код в таком случае может получиться лажей...
...
#define true false
#define false true
...
int main()
{
bool a=false;
bool b=true;
}
```

Comment: Я естественно проверял. Но по просто интересно, когда наступит предел такому "перепереопределению". Почему бы компилятору скажем, проделав переопределение дважды, не выполнить это еще раз дважды, а потом еще раз? По идее строится цепочка вроде true->false->true->false->...

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, никакой цепочки не будет: сначала выполнится первый дефайн, заменив все true на false, а потом второй, заменив все false на true. Если я ошибаюсь, пусть меня кто-нибудь поправит.

Comment: @insolor, так и есть. Посмотрите дополнение к ответу

Comment: Советую кроме логических рассуждений обратится к опыту (gcc -E или g++ это в данном случае одно и то же).